# Should posting of contact details in questions be prevented?

Tags: discussion

In relation to this post... [EASY Q.U.E.S.T.IO.N, HOW TO [on hold]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24063127/easy-q-u-e-s-t-io-n-how-to?noredirect=1)

The OP simply lists a number of fairly unrelated questions (for want of a better word) and finishes up with "I need a friend to help me" followed by facebook, twitter and gmail contact details (which I removed).

Aside from it being unclear as to whether any of those details actually belong to the OP, it's a particularly naive thing to do in my opinion.

Opportunities for spam, phishing or any other number of nefarious outcomes of people contacting the OP.

So, should Stack Overflow censor anything in a question which looks like it is direct contact information?

EDIT: In reference to the response from Servy, my question is indeed in respect to auto-censorship.

If I post code which might involve email client/server software (for example) I'd use `myname@someaddress.com` rather than give away personal details. If that is within a code-block then auto-censorship shouldn't apply.

Similarly for a URL to a website I'll often use `http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/index.html` unless the site is a public one and I need people to test the link against my code.

Comment: No. I link to my OkCupid profile in every one of my posts, and it is always appropriate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you mean automatically, then no.  That's error prone, can end up removing information important to a question, and easily subverted.

If you mean manually, by having people edit it out as you have, then yes.  It is entirely appropriate to edit out contact information like that.

Comment: Good point - I suppose I did mean auto-censorship. It worries me slightly when someone naive enough to post their details saying "I need a friend" as much as it worries me that they're not actually that naive but, instead, they're looking for naive people to be their "friend".

Comment: It might be a good idea to put a warning up if something looks like an e-mail or phone number in the body, though. Like the warning that comes up for questions which might be subjective, but more along the lines of "It appears that your question / answer may contain personal contact information. Please remove those details, or ignore this message if it is in error". Unless there already is such a message, in which case, yay.