# Should the poster's email address be edited out of a question?

Tags: discussion, email

A user on the Arduino site recently posted, as his first question, a rather rambling question, ending with his email address. I have enough rep to edit posts, and cleaned up most of the grammar and spelling.

My question is: **Is it OK to ask (or imply) that you want help via email?**

Doesn't such a question effectively nullify the point of this site, because any answers given by email benefit only the poster and nobody else?

I looked through the FAQ, and searched Meta (here) for whether or not that is acceptable without finding a clear answer.

My gut feeling is **no**, because problems solved "off-site" do not effectively become part of the StackExchange knowledge-base, and the answers are not subjected to peer-review.

If the post needs clarification, that is what comments are for, surely?

Comment: Does arduino not have its own meta? What communities do is going to differ slightly on each site, so you should ask questions of policy on the per-site meta, or the overall meta.se, rather than meta for a different site.

Comment: Oh, OK, sure. I thought this was more like a general policy thing, that wouldn't vary from site to site. There's a related post for example: [Can I add my email address on a comment or post?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251947/can-i-add-my-email-address-on-a-comment-or-post) - I took this sort of question as being broad enough to be asked here.

Comment: It looks like it *was* relevant because there is a duplicate <http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258513/should-posting-of-contact-details-in-questions-be-prevented> that I somehow did not find. The answer there appeared to be that it was OK to edit out the personal information.

Comment: Nick: this site is for discussing issues on [so], there's [meta.se] for

Comment: Ah I see, noted. Sorry for the confusion.